# PHP handling not working

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me why does this code not works? On the input it does not says Wellcome + The name but only Welcome.

```
<body>
   <div class="bdiv">
   <h1 style="text-align: center;">Head-text</h1>
   Username: <input placeholder ="Enter your username here..." class="textbox" type="text" name="name" >
   <input type="submit" class="cks" >
   Welcome: <?php echo $POST('name'); ?>
   <div class="load"><img src="agif.gif"/></div>
   <p class="t1">test</p>
   <p class="t2">test </p>
   <p class="t3">Test</p>
   <p class="t4">test</p>

   <script>
      $('.cks').click (function() {
         $('.textbox').delay(5000).fadeOut();
         $('.load').fadeIn('10000000');
         $('.t1').delay(500).fadeIn('100000')
         $('.t2').delay(1000).fadeIn('100000')
      });
   </script>
   </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: Where do you have the `<form>` tag?

Comment: please study how to use basic php : http://www.phptherightway.com

Comment: Why `session_start()` @bcesars? There is no session indicated here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Lotta *where's and why's* - *Mornin' Sam!*

Comment: My bad. I assumed there is an session in this code.

Comment: Some *who's* and *what's* too! *Mornin' Ralph!*

Comment: Just no *when's* – @JayBlanchard *why?*

Comment: Well played @Fred-ii- I would assume *when* is *now*.

Comment: Is [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) a good time? – @JayBlanchard

Comment: Just then it was @Fred-ii- ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This part of your code: `echo $POST('name');` is supposed to read as: `echo $_POST['name'];`

You missed the underscore between `$` and `POST`.

- It's a superglobal: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

I also do not see an opening `<form>` tag. I just see the closing `</form>` tag.

- Forms default to a GET method if omitted.

Therefore it needs to resemble this:

```
<form action="your_handler.php" method="post">
```

Comment: I felt super bad for answering this question but your edit on my answer gave me a bit more satisfaction. Thanks @Fred-ii- .

Comment: @SviatoslavVolkov What changes? Present them to me