# Radio buttons need to stay checked

Tags: php, html, radio-button, joomla3.0

I need to make two radio buttons that stay checked after submission. I am making this inside a Joomla article. I installed DirectPHP so I can use php and javascript. The code i have till now:

```
<form>
<input name="button" type="radio" value="1" id="button1" /> 
<input name="button" type="radio" value="2" id="button2" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why 2 opening form tags?

Comment: Please explain stay checked? must they be checked when going to the next page? must they be checked when posting to the server? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: After submission you have to check with php whether at button 1, `$_POST['button1']==1` if it is, you `echo 'checked';` inside of the tag.

Comment: The button that is checked by the user needs to stay checked after you click the submit button. even when you reload

Comment: Is there any place this content is saved, like a database or files etc?

Comment: sidenote: form defaults to GET if the method is omitted

Comment: *"I installed DirectPHP so I can use php and javascript."* - so, where's the JS to go with this? or is that irrelevant?

Comment: @Fred-ii- The GET comment? I have: `or GET` + in the first version of his question, he used `POST`

Comment: @Loko ah I see. That is what we call a *"Stealth edit"*. Where they overwrote it without marking it as an edit.

Comment: voted to close as unclear. Post your real/full code along with your PHP and JS if you're using that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FYI:**
Forms default to GET if the method is omitted.

- Doing `<form>` is equivalent to doing `<form method="get">`

If your PHP is using POST arrays, then you will need to specify the method and have not provided any additional code in your question.

I.e.: `<form method="post">`

Check inside of the input tags like this:

```
<form>
<input name="button" type="radio" value="1" id="button1" <?php if($_GET["button"]==1 ){ echo "checked"; }?> /> 
<input name="button" type="radio" value="2" id="button2" <?php if($_GET["button"]==2 ){ echo "checked"; }?> />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

change names and methods according to what you want.

- Sidenote: Change `GET` to `POST` if your PHP is using POST arrays and specify a "post" method.

Comment: LOL, totally same answer :-) yours is more complete though

Comment: @Fred-ii- What do you mean? Like small typo's or something?

Comment: @Loko forms default to GET. I'm using $_REQUEST now in my answer

Comment: `<form>` [read my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575066/radio-buttons-need-to-stay-checked#comment49220217_30575066) @Loko

Comment: @Fred-ii- I responded. I also have a comment with: /*or GET */ this depends on what OP wants. OP used POST before he editted the question.

Comment: @Loko D'oh! You're right

Comment: @Loko I would have asked the OP for their PHP code. As it stands, their question is unclear, and as per their "Stealth edit". I voted to close as unclear and they mention "JS".

Comment: @Fred-ii- I took a long time to answer as well because of the random JS part. I answered 6 minutes after the edit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the edit to clarify everything(once again:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811748/php-handling-not-working/28811818#28811818). BTW I checked out your website and the *questions/answers on stackoverflow* part is bugged for me. Dunno if theres something with my end or your website. The only part that's a link for me is 'questions'. (I'll edit this out as soon as you read this.)

Comment: @Loko you're welcome, glad to have been of help. *questions/answers on stackoverflow* - yeah that link's weird and I haven't fixed it yet. It only works if you put your mouse over the beginning of "questions" lol - I'll fix that today or tomorrow. Thanks for reminding me. I tend to forget at times.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This conversation is going completely off topic, but when I inspect it in chrome, I can see that a div overlaps the other part of the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<input name="button" type="radio" value="1" id="button1"<?php if ($_REQUEST['button1'] === 1) echo " checked"; ?>/> 
<input name="button" type="radio" value="2" id="button2"<?php if ($_REQUEST['button2'] === 1) echo " checked"; ?>/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
  <input name="button1" type="radio" value="1" id="button1" <?php if ($_REQUEST[ 'button1']===1 ) echo "checked"; ?>/>
  <input name="button2" type="radio" value="2" id="button2" <?php if ($_REQUEST[ 'button2']===2 ) echo "checked"; ?>/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```